# Wireless card unclaimed by driver, not working

Tags: 13.04, wireless, drivers

So, my wireless card is reporting all feature correctly, but remained unclaimed by the driver.

Someone suggested that it could be a PCI controller issue. Any ideas where to start.

lscpi -v below.

```
05:00.0 Network controller: Atheros Communications Inc. AR9300 Wireless LAN adaptor (rev 01) 
    Subsystem: Atheros Communications Inc. Device 3116 
    Flags: fast devsel, IRQ 19 
    Memory at f7100000 (64-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=128K] 
    Expansion ROM at f7120000 [disabled] [size=64K] 
    Capabilities: [40] Power Management version 3 
    Capabilities: [50] MSI: Enable- Count=1/4 Maskable+ 64bit+ 
    Capabilities: [70] Express Endpoint, MSI 00 
    Capabilities: [100] Advanced Error Reporting 
    Capabilities: [140] Virtual Channel 
    Capabilities: [300] Device Serial Number 00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00
```

Answer (score 0):

Please open a terminal and run:

```
lspci -nn
```

Is your device enumerated Atheros Communications Inc. AR9300 Wireless LAN adaptor [168c:0030]? If so, I suspect it is not covered in Ubuntu 13.04. Please check:

```
modinfo ath9k | grep 0030
```

If it reports:

```
alias:           pci:v0000168Cd00000032sv0000185Fsd00003027bc*sc*i*
alias:           pci:v0000168Cd00000030sv*sd*bc*sc*i* 
alias            pci:v0000168Cd0000002Asv0000185Fsd0000309Dbc*sc*i* 
alias:           pci:v0000168Cd0000002Asv00001A32sd00000306bc*sc*i*
```

Then your device is covered. If it is, then load the module:

```
sudo modprobe ath9k
```

Does your device come to life?

If it is not covered, I suggest you upgrade to Ubuntu 13.10.

It appears that your device *is* covered by the driver ath9k. First, load it:

```
sudo modprobe ath9k
```

See if a wireless interface was created:

```
iwconfig
```

Make sure the wireless switch is correctly set:

```
rfkill list all
```

And check the log for errors, warnings, etc.:

```
dmesg | grep -e wlan -e ath
```

Comment: Tried 13.10, still not supported. Did some research(with your info as help), and it turns out the chip is supported, but not the pci mini port. But its a newer gen card, so it just a matter of waiting.

Comment: So what is the ID of the card? lspci -nn | grep 0280

Comment: lspci reports `05:00.0 Network controller [0280]: Qualcomm Atheros AR93xx Wireless Network Adapter [168c:0030] (rev 01)`  And modinfo reports `alias:          pci:v0000168Cd00000030sv*sd*bc*sc*i*`